# Is W a subspace of P x P?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W \subset P \times P$ be given below, (here $P = \mathbb{R}[x]$)

$W = \{ (f(x), g(x)) \in P \times P| f(2) = 0 \land g^{\prime}(0) = 0 \}$.

Is W a subspace of $P \times P$? Prove or disprove.

I'm so lost, please help.

Comment: Is the set closed under vector addition? What about scalar multiplication? Is the identity vector in $W$? Check each of those conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need to show $W$ satisfies in order to check it is a subspace?

Let's first show that $W$ is closed under addition and I'll leave you to check the other condition(s).

Let $(f,g), (p,q) \in W$. $(f,g)+(p,q) = (f+p,g+q)$.

$$(f+p)(0) = f(0)+p(0)=0+0$$
$$(g+q)'(0) = g'(0)+q'(0) = 0+0$$

So $(f+p,g+q) \in W$.

If you show that $W$ contains the zero element of $P \times P$ and that it's also closed under multiplication by scalars from $\mathbb{R}$, you're done.